# A header displays differently on ie/safari and on chrome. How to make it the same

Tags: html, css, rendering

CSS

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    color: #FC0;
    background-color: #FC0;
}
```

[ie/safari (ie11)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQQ9r.jpg)
[chrome (77)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1dyz.jpg)

I want it to look like the ie screenshot on all platforms. Chrome on my iphone 8+ renders the same as ie but on pc it is different. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: Add your supporting HTML snippet as well.

Comment: add u r html code also

Comment: Please add full header html with css of each item.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a php include for the header and miraculously every browser now looks the same. I don't know why. But it worked.